# Help! I have a function a point, and a rate of change... how do I find the direction?

Tags: calculus

I have an exam coming up and on one of the sample exams I came across this problem. I have $f(x,y) = xy^2$, $P(-1,1)$, and $ROC = 2$. The question s asking for the direction and I'm not sure how to how to go about it since we were only shown how to get the rate of change given $u$ or how to get the direction of the min/max rate of change.

Any pointers will be extremely appreciated....

Comment: Let $u = <\cos \theta,\sin \theta>$ for some unknown $\theta$.  Find the directional derivative $D_{u}(f)(-1,1)$ for that direction.  Then solve $D_{u}(f) = 2$ for $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm really hoping this is what the prof will be looking for if it comes up since he never showed us an example with this kind of problem. He only explained that Du(f) =  gradient of f * u or ||gradient of f||cos(theta)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the gradient of a function points in a direction of maximum increase of change

Here, we have $f=xy^2\implies \nabla f=\hat xy^2+\hat y 2xy$.

At the point $(-1,1)$, $\nabla f=\hat x+\hat y2$.

---

The directional derivative $\frac{df}{du}$ along the direction of the unit vector $\hat u=\hat xu_x+\hat yu_y$ is defined as

$$\frac{df}{du}=\hat u \cdot \nabla f$$

Now, we are given that $\frac{df}{du}=2$ at the point $(-1,1)$. Thus,

$$\hat u \cdot (\hat x+\hat y2)=u_x+2u_y=2 \tag 1$$

and

$$u_x^2+u_y^2=1\tag 2$$

whereupon solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously for $u_x$ and $u_y$ yields two solutions $(i)$ $u_x=4/5$ and $u_y=3/5$ and $(ii)$ $u_x=0$ and $u_y=1$.

Thus, the direction for which the rate of change is $2$ is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\hat u=\hat x\frac45+\hat y\frac35}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\hat u=\hat y}$$

Comment: There's one more solution, namely $\hat{y}$. (It's pretty clear geometrically that there must be two solutions, isn't it?)

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, you are correct.  $u_x=0$ is a solution.  I added the second solution.  +1 for catching this!

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much!!! :D

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.